# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /var/www/likeslomakkeet/controllers/petitions_controller.php on line 33

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm getting: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /var/www/likeslomakkeet/controllers/petitions_controller.php on line 33

with the code below. I'm not sure why as I have also defined $name correctly in the model with var $name = 'Petition';
The error comes out when I put custom query.

Anyone has any suggestions?

```
function index() {
        if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id') != 1) {
            $commune_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.commune_id');
            $commune_id = $this->Petition->Commune->findbyId($commune_id);
            $commune_id = $this->Petition->Commune->find('all',array('conditions' => array('group' => $commune_id['Commune']['group'])));
            debug($commune_id);
            $count = count($commune_id);
            $i=1;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `petitions` WHERE `commune_id` = ";
            foreach($commune_id as $commune_ids){
                if($i==1){
                $sql .= $commune_ids['Commune']['id'];
                }else{
                $sql .= " OR `commune_id` = ".$commune_ids['Commune']['id'];
                }
            /*if($i != $count){
            $this->paginate = array(
                'or' => array(
                    array('Petition.commune_id LIKE' => $commune_ids['Commune']['id'] . ","),
                    //array('Petition.commune_id LIKE' => "," . $commune_ids['Commune']['id'] . ",")
                    ),
                'limit' => 10
            );
            }*/
            $i++;
            }
            $query = $this->Petiton->query($sql);
            debug($query);
        }
        $this->Petition->recursive = 0;
        $petitions = $this->paginate();
        $this->set('petitions', $petitions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one:

```
$this->Petiton
          ^^^
```

Add an `i`.

Comment: I need to sleep... Thanks Casper!

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem like this line:

```
$this->loadModel('Petiton');
```